# Bug of the socket output, is not it?

Tags: pynodes

Input and output sockets do not work the same way. The picture seen sockets input and output node "ObjectProps". The socket input button is drawn, while the output socket - no. Who knows the reason? How to make a button in the output socket?
[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is a missing feature of the node API. There is a patch for this ready and waiting, but since it changes the way node sockets look i want to wait for green light from scripters before committing to trunk.

See [bf-committers thread](http://lists.blender.org/pipermail/bf-committers/2013-September/041633.html)

UPDATE: This feature has been added in trunk now ([r60661](https://projects.blender.org/scm/viewvc.php?view=rev&root=bf-blender&revision=60661)). Socket draw functions are responsible for drawing only labels if that is the desired behavior, otherwise inputs and outputs draw the same way. See the [API changes wiki page](http://wiki.blender.org/index.php/Extensions:2.6/Py/API_Changes#Python_Node_Output_Drawing_.28r60661.29).

Comment: I want to draw a button on the socket output. But it does not work. How can draw a button on the socket output?

The socket input is possible, and in the socket output is not possible. Why?

Comment: (Also note: in the Properties of N-panel socket output is not adjudged. Input socket is there)

Comment: This is just what that patch fixes. You can then use the socket.in_out and socket.is_linked properties to distinguish by input/output and connection to produce the behavior you want.

Comment: Need to change the module
source/blender/editors/space_node/drawnode.c
 and compile the application Blender?

Can you give a link to the finished compiled Blender with this patch?